# How to feature staple to MySites Master Page?

Tags: feature-stapling, my-site, my-profile

Is there a way to feature staple to the MySites site definition?

I want to be able to style it via the Master Page.

Comment: Might as well accept some answers. Your rating is not doing well and that makes a difference on exchange sites.

Comment: go to Master Pages in SharePoint Designer then click on "mysite15.master" and edit the file as required.

Answer (score 3):

You need to staple to SPSPERS#0 template. See [this technet post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsocialcomputing/thread/ade6b36e-b4aa-4a0d-98e8-31344136829f).